# How do I produce a German umlaut with KMK

Tags: python, raspberry-pi-pico, kmk

I am making a custom keyboard with KMK / MicroPython on a Raspberry Pi Pico to be used with OSX.

I would like it to have convenient access to German umlauts (äÄöÖüÜ), so I defined a dedicated `KC.UMLAUT` key, which, when pressed together with <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>, or <kbd>U</kbd> should produce the corresponding umlaut. When <kbd>shift</kbd> is pressed too, it should send the capitalized version.

Here is what I have:

```py
import board

from kmk.kmk_keyboard import KMKKeyboard
from kmk.keys import KC, make_key
from kmk.handlers.sequences import simple_key_sequence
from kmk.modules.combos import Combos, Sequence

keyboard = KMKKeyboard()

AUML = simple_key_sequence( ( KC.LALT(KC.U), KC.A,))
AUML_CAP = simple_key_sequence( ( KC.LALT(KC.U), KC.RSFT(KC.A),))

make_key(
    KC.NO.code,
    names=(
        'UMLAUT',
    )
)

combos = Combos()
combos.combos = [
    Sequence((KC.UMLAUT, KC.A), AUML),
    Sequence((KC.UMLAUT, KC.RSFT, KC.A), AUML_CAP),
    # ... I also have Sequences for O and U
]

keyboard.keymap = [
    [
        KC.A, KC.O, KC.U, 
        KC.UMLAUT, KC.RSFT,
    ]
]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    keyboard.go()
```

However, this approach is flawed in many ways:

Only the first press of <kbd>umlaut</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> produces an "ä" character. Subsequent presses (with umlaut held down) give a regular "a" again. Also, <kbd>umlaut</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd> have to be pressed in that order -- <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>umlaut</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> won't work.

Last but not least, I don't like how I need separate definitions for the shifted behavior. It feels like I am on the wrong track here. Surely there is a better (and less verbose) way to do such a basic thing?

Comment: Never had hands-on experience with it, but i can remember that there is `prefer_hold=True` keyword, maybe it helps you somehow

Comment: @leberknecht I think ```prefer_hold``` is only applicable with the HoldTap keycodes and when switching between layers (with ```KC.LT()``` for example). Maybe I should investigate putting my umlauts on their own layer, but otherwise it seems to me that prefer_hold is orthogonal to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found for myself was to use the US International Keyboard Layout which offers german Umlaute with the following shortcuts:

- Right-Alt + Q = ä
- Right-Alt + Y = ü
- Right-Alt + P = ö

Using this I've created the following combos:

```py
combos.combos = [
    Chord((KC.A, KC.S), KC.RALT(KC.Q), timeout=30),
    Chord((KC.S, KC.D), KC.RALT(KC.S), timeout=30),
    Chord((KC.U, KC.I), KC.RALT(KC.Y), timeout=30),
    Chord((KC.O, KC.P), KC.RALT(KC.P), timeout=30),
]
```

This solution works in combination with the SHIFT modifier as well.

There is probably another way by using make_key() to create custom keys.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am living with (for now):

```py
import board

from kmk.kmk_keyboard import KMKKeyboard
from kmk.keys import KC
from kmk.modules.holdtap import HoldTap
holdtap = HoldTap()

# tap => ¨, hold => KC.LALT
LALT = KC.HT(KC.LALT(KC.U), KC.LALT)

keyboard.modules.append(holdtap)
```

Holding down the key lets it act as regular `alt` key (so 'ß' still works). Tapping it followed by any of `aouAOU` renders the corresponding umlaut.

This doesn't *quite* answer my original question. It's the compromise I've settled for.